# IText5 Unable to read PDF which has electronic signature

Tags: itext

I have a pdf document which is generated by an electronic signature utility after a user has entered data and electronically signed the document. When it comes back to us, I want to grad data from the form fields and extract value from textbox, combo, checkboxes etc.

I cam up with something like this looking at some examples.

All the Acrofields show is that there are no fields on the pdf.

I can share the pdf if you wish. I m not sure if I m in the right direction. Also, I tried using the line by line reading mechanism but then I dont get the user inputs from checkboxes, text fields etc.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
//PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
//PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(src, FileMode.Create));

AcroFields form = reader.AcroFields;

foreach(String key in form.Fields.Keys){
    int type = form.GetFieldType(key);
    switch (type)
    {
        case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_CHECKBOX:
            Console.WriteLine("Checkbox");
            break;
       ........
..........
```

Comment: I would assume the form is flattened during signing. But please share an example pdf to check that assumption.

Comment: Yes, the form is flattened, is there another way to read it, or another tool, where can I upload the data pdf?

Comment: As soon as you flatten a form, it is not an AcroForm anymore, it merely had the looks of a form. If you want to access form contents, don't flatten.

Comment: Is there any way to access the data? Obviously, flattening is something out of my control as the eSignature software does it, I might have to go down the path of OCR etc

Comment: you can try text extraction. But the AcroForm field names are lost.